# Jenkins DSL Seed Job Run commands after the Job is created

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I am creating a seed job which basically created a jenkins pipeline to onboard a new service which builds and deploys to ECR/EKS.
Below is my Jenkins DSL script (Have attached sample)

```
pipelineJob('example') {
    definition {
        cps {
            script(readFileFromWorkspace('project-a-workflow.groovy'))
            sandbox()
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run few terraform and aws commands after this pipeline is created.
So whenever I run this DSL Seed job, the pipeline should be created and My tf/AWS commands should be executed. (TF/AWS commands will not be included in my onboard pipeline which is created by seed job.